# PHP mail function returns true but doesn't send mail on local

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, localhost

Im trying to send a simple mail on my local machine to my gmail account. Mail() always returns TRUE but never send anything.

This is the simple PHP code i'm running

```
    $header = "From: xyz@gmail.com\r\n"; 
    $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 

    if(mail("zyx@gmail.com", "This some subject", "This is some message body",$header))  
        echo "Sent"; 
    else  
        echo "Not sent";
```

I'm now using postfix (before it was sendmail).

This is /var/log/mail.log

> Dec 30 09:50:14 localhost postfix/pickup[7452]: BB3E3861B90: uid=33 from = www-data
>
> Dec 30 09:50:14 localhost postfix/cleanup[7677]: BB3E3861B90: message-id=<20151230142014.BB3E3861B90@daniel-Inspiron-N4050>
>
> Dec 30 09:50:14 localhost postfix/qmgr[1542]: BB3E3861B90: from=, size=476, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Dec 30 09:50:14 localhost postfix/error[7679]: BB3E3861B90: to=, relay=none, delay=0.28, delays=0.16/0/0/0.12, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (citr$
>
> Dec 30 09:50:14 localhost postfix/cleanup[7677]: EC875861B91: message-id=<20151230142014.EC875861B91@daniel-Inspiron-N4050>
>
> Dec 30 09:50:15 localhost postfix/bounce[7680]: BB3E3861B90: sender non-delivery notification: EC875861B91
>
> Dec 30 09:50:15 localhost postfix/qmgr[1542]: EC875861B91: from=<>, size=2279, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Dec 30 09:50:15 localhost postfix/qmgr[1542]: BB3E3861B90: removed
>
> Dec 30 09:50:15 localhost postfix/local[7683]: EC875861B91: to=, relay=local, delay=0.15, delays=0.07/0/0/0.08, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent ($
>
> Dec 30 09:50:15 localhost postfix/qmgr[1542]: EC875861B91: removed

I also check and there's not mail queue.

---

I have also tried all solutions exposed here [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)

- Make sure actually call the mail() function
- Check server's mail logs
- Don't use the error suppression operator
- Check to see if mail() returns true or false: returns true
- Check spam folders / Prevent your email from being flagged as spam
- Make sure supply mail headers
- Make sure mail headers do not have a syntax error
- Make sure recipient value is correct: are my personal emails
- Send to multiple accounts
- If on localhost, make sure you have a mail server set up

Thanks!

Comment: configure smtp for this

Comment: Postfix (or the remote side) seems to be bouncing your messages. `status=bounced`

Comment: @devpro why do I need to configure smtp? Im running Linux Elementary-OS